# How to update header parameter and sent the same to Controller using AOP in Spring/Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, aop, spring-aop

How to update header parameter and sent the same to Controller using AOP in Spring/Spring boot? I am able to add but not able to send it to the controller. I am getting null value in the controller. I don't want to use @Around.

```
  @Before("PointcutDefinition.controllerLayer()")
  public Object beforeAdvice(JoinPoint joinPoint)
  {
    HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
    request.setAttribute("traceId", ServiceUtil.getTraceId());
    return request;
  }
```

Update:

I was able to update traceId using the following code.

```
  @Around("execution(* com.test.api.*.*(..)) && " + "args(traceId,..)")
  public Object setTraceId(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, String traceId) throws Throwable
  {
    String newTraceId = ServiceUtil.getTraceId();
    Object result = joinPoint.proceed(new Object[]
    { newTraceId, "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "" });
    return result;
  }
```

In my Controller, I have multiple methods with a different number of arguments. But the first argument in all the method is traceId. I would like to update traceId alone and leave the other parameter as it is. But in the above approach, I am compelled to pass all the arguments. Is there a way I can update the first param alone and send the remaining parameters untouched.

Comment: Is that a header or an attribute you want to set?

Comment: My Controller class ->  public ResponseEntity<String> loginSession(@RequestHeader(value = "traceId", required = false) String traceId,...)     I would like to set value for traceId.

Comment: Why do not you want to use @Around?

Comment: I am fine using @Around (If it is the only way to achieve this). I was under the impression that, we should use Around only if we would like to do something before and after calling the method. But in my case, i would like to do something before calling the method and not after calling the method.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do that using @Around. I believe it cannot be achieved using @Before.

```
  @Around("execution(* com.test.api.*.*(..)) && " + "args(traceId,..)")
  public Object setTraceId(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, String traceId) throws Throwable
  {
    String newTraceId = ServiceUtil.getTraceId();
    Object[] obj = joinPoint.getArgs();
    obj[0] = newTraceId;
    return joinPoint.proceed(obj);
  }
```

Comment: In your first try I don't see how setting an attribute on the request is going to result in getting an extra header value.  A request attribute is not a header.

Comment: You are correct @Robert Moskal. It didn’t strike me.

Answer (score 0):

Your trouble lies not in the @Before annotation, but in mistakenly setting an attribute on the HttpServletRequest instead of a header.  Attribute != Header. So, of course, that parameter is going to be null in your controller.

The headers on HttpServletRequest are read only.  You'll need to wrap the request in a HttpServletRequestWrapper and do all sorts of work in order to manage the original headers and your custom ones.  There are many exampless, including a complete one here: https://wilddiary.com/adding-custom-headers-java-httpservletrequest/

It introduces a MutableHttpServletRequest  that extends HttpServletRequestWrapper. You'll have keep state on your custom headers and mere them with the original ones. You'll have to override getHeader and getHeaderNames!

Your @Before code would look something like this:

```
HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
MutableHttpServletRequest wrappedRequest = new MutableHttpServletRequest(request);
request.putHeader("traceId", ServiceUtil.getTraceId());
return request;
```

However, this seems like such a long way to go in order to get a tiny bit of functionality (unless you need to do it again and again).  For a one-off I'd just use the @Around technique.

All this ceremony to add a value to a map!